# Ommiting node_modules in vsc symbol search

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to ommit node_modules results from symbol searching in visual studio code?

When you go like:
`cmd + P` then type `#` you are able to search by symbols in the project, but results contains node_modules items. I'd like to aviod them

Comment: you can't use the `search.exclude` setting?

Comment: @starball No. That does not work. I have node_modules both in my user settings and workspace settings and neither has any effect.